# How do i change default option in select Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, select, default

I have this select, where i load a bunch of countries.
After the user selects one, he will go to another page where he searches for information. If he selected a country before he should have that country selected by default (on another select, in another page, which contains the same countries).

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="selecionarPaisPreferencia" class="select">Pais</label>
    <select name="selecionarPaisPreferencia" id="SlSelecionarPaisPreferencia"></select>
</div>
```

How do i change the default option in a select, before loading the page.

BTW: i have already stored the name of the country he selected in a global variable.

i load the options dinamically since im not using database this is for an exercise.

```
for (i = 0; i < countrys.length; i++) {
    $("#SLSelectPaisConsulta").append('<option data-pais="' + countrys[i] + '">' + countrys[i] + '</option>');
    $("#SlSelecionarPaisPreferencia").append('<option data-pais="' + countrys[i] + '">' + countrys[i] + '</option>');
}
```

Comment: It's "countries". Just trying to save you some embarrassment when your code is seen by your colleagues.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#selecionarPaisPreferencia').val('country_name_value_here');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes another way to do it, if you have the value to be selected in `SelectedValue`:

```
$("#SlSelecionarPaisPreferencia").find('[value="'+SelectedValue+'"]').attr("selected", true);
```

For the sake of completeness, it's important to note that using `val()` directly should be more efficient, but `val()` won't work with multiple choice selects, while this method will work in single or multiple choice selects. You just have to call it one time for each value you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$("#SlSelecionarPaisPreferencia").val(selectedPais);
```

Or

```
$("#SlSelecionarPaisPreferencia")
    .children(':contains('+selectedPais+')').prop('selected',true);
```

Or:

```
$("#SlSelecionarPaisPreferencia > option:contains("+selectedPais+")").prop('selected',true);
```